# Jquery Autocomplete not showing results "$map is not defined"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, visual-studio-2013, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to set up a jquery autocomplete function, but when I enter text no suggestions appear.

The project is MVC .NET VS2013.

Using the debugger in Chrome I can see that the correct suggestions are being generated, but do not show on the page.  Using firebug in firefox has the same results.

Also, I am getting an "$map is not defined" error.  It looks like this means jquery-ui is not being loaded, but I am at a loss as I have tried loading it in the _layout included as a part of the the jquery bundle, as it's own bundle, as well as referenced directly on the view, but none have any effect (jquery-ui always referenced after jquery.js).

Is there a specific way jquery-ui should be referenced in MVC projects?

Jquery:

```
  <p>
@Html.TextBox("Restaurant")
<input type="submit" id="Restaurant" value="Submit" />
</p>
 @section scripts {

<section class="scripts">

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Restaurant").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Map/Search",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($map(data, function (item) {

                        return {
                            label: item.value,
                            value: item.label

                            };
                     }
                    ))

                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
})
</script>
</section>
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "$.map"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part of your code

```
response($map(data, function (item) {
```

to

```
response($.map(data, function (item) {
```

or you can refactor the success callback function to:

```
success: function (data) {
    var items = $.map(data, function (item){
        return {
            label: item.value,
            value: item.label
        };
    });
    response(items);
}
```